# How to get the values from the Hashmap without using Iterator?

Tags: java, iterator, maps

```
Iterator iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) 
{
    Map.Entry mapEntry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
System.out.println("The key is: " + mapEntry.getKey() + ",value is :" + mapEntry.getValue());

}
```

This is my code. Now i don't want to use Iterator to get the values.
Please help me to find best solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
Map<String, Object> map = .....;//Initialization here
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    // write your code here
}
```

//If you are just using keys of the Map

```
for (Object value : map.values()) {
     // write your code here
}
```

//If you are just using values from your Map

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Object value = entry.getValue();
    // you code here
}
```

//If you want both Keys and values

//All are without using Iterator of the Map

Comment: If I remember correctly, the iterator is still used here, only hidden from view ;-)

Comment: Yes, exactly. But I assumed that OP meant not to create/use instance of Iterator Interface explicitly. :)

Comment: Yes... Its Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Map.entrySet().stream().map(o -> o.getValue()).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: Plain code answers are often not very much appreciated. Please describe your answer as complete as possible.

Comment: Does this avoid iterators all together (no allocations involved)?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(String key : map.keySet()) {
   System.out.println("The key is: " + key + ",value is :" + map.get(key));
}
```

same result and iterator is gone =)

Comment: You are still using iterator - map.keySet().

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print all the values without using loop or iterator from map you can do like this

`Map <Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
map.put(1, "Hello");
map.put(2, "Welcome");
System.out.println(map.values().toString());`

You can store it in variable as a string

`String value = map.values().toString();`

Hope this helps!