# Get values from Object into map

Tags: java

I have this data structure:

```
public class Country {
    private final String country;
    private final String alpha;
    private final String number;
    // constructor and getters
}

Map<String, Country> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("AT", new Country("Austria", "AUT", "040");
```

How I can get the value when I search by key `Austria` or `AUT`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the values from the Hashmap without using Iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29115392/how-to-get-the-values-from-the-hashmap-without-using-iterator)

Comment: Yes, but I have several values. Can you show me code example please? It's not very clear.

Comment: You go over the values of the `Map` with the `values()` method and picks the value you want based on the search criteria you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can't from that map other then iterating the values of the entry set and testing each. That is not a recommendable way. However, there are solutions to your problem like e.g. having a custom index Map, containing all search indexes as Keys. Remember, that Maps contain references to their values. So the value Object is only stored once in memory.

A custom index would be very easy in your case, as every field value is unique. No two countries are named the same, same for country code, phone prefix and what ever alpha is.
So have in mind that my example only will work under that condition of uniquenes:

```
public class Example
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Map<String, Country> index = new TreeMap<>();

        Country ct = new Country("Austria", "AUT", "040");

        index.put("AT", ct);
        index.put("Austria", ct);
        index.put("AUT", ct);
        index.put("040", ct);

        ct = new Country("Midgard", "MIG", "091");

        index.put("MG", ct);
        index.put("Midgard", ct);
        index.put("MIG", ct);
        index.put("091", ct);

        ct = new Country("Somwhere Else", "SWE", "055");

        index.put("SW", ct);
        index.put("Somwhere Else", ct);
        index.put("SWE", ct);
        index.put("055", ct);

        System.out.println(index.get("Austria").toString());
    }
}
```

If you have not unique data you need a more complex index model like e.g. `Map<String, List<Country>>` that can return multiple values for a search term. If it becomes more complex or much more data, you might want to consider a fulltext indexer, such as Lucene or prefere to store your data into a database and use it's search tools.

Comment: How about using Google Guava - HashBasedTable?

Comment: I am not familliar with Guava. If it looks promising to you, just try it out.